# I keep getting connected and disconnected when I'm on the phone

Tags: verbs, idioms

In a bad phone connection and when it sucks, how would you say that the conversation between you and the second person on the other side keeps getting connected and disconnected?
Is there any verb/idiom which can encapsulate this concept when it comes to phone concersations?

Comment: Brief interruptions of a phone conversation are not the same as being "disconnected". When you are disconnected the call is over and you have to dial again. You can talk about someone "breaking up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **connection** (or **signal**) **keeps dropping out**, or the **signal** (or **connection**) **is up and down**. Various similar expressions exist, too.

Comment: Is it the most common one @SamBC?

Comment: would it work to say: "the connection is dropping out" or "your voice is dropping out"?

Comment: "The connection is dropping out" is fine; "your voice is dropping out" would seem unusual, as it would imply the problem is with their voice.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine.

This was happening to me yesterday with my cell phone. I kept getting disconnected. The phone calls were ended about five times per call.  All afternoon. It was very frustrating. Today, the service seems fine. Connected and disconnected is traditionally associated with landlines, but can also be used for cell phones AKA mobiles.

Of course, we also say for mobile phones: ***My calls were being dropped.***

Idiom: ***My calls were dropped. My calls were being dropped.***

Comment: being dropped or dropped out?